# Windows power plan has no effect on laptop

Tags: laptop, windows-8.1, power

Out of nowhere power plan stopped working, looks like it just stuck on power saver. All I did was connected from work for few minutes, when came home logged in and it was on "High performance" but works like on "Power saver". I can change it but nothing happens. Tried creating new plan (and deleting it). Installed all updates, restarted, disconnecting all usb devices\power supply\monitor.

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>powercfg -l
Existing Power Schemes (* Active)
-----------------------------------
Power Scheme GUID: 381b4222-f694-41f0-9685-ff5bb260df2e  (Balanced)
Power Scheme GUID: 6b9d1846-9700-477a-98e2-05ce313dbcb5  (My Custom Plan 1)
Power Scheme GUID: 8c5e7fda-e8bf-4a96-9a85-a6e23a8c635c  (High performance) *
Power Scheme GUID: a1841308-3541-4fab-bc81-f71556f20b4a  (Power saver)
```

[Power Efficiency Diagnostics Report](http://jsfiddle.net/Ltav99f7/)

I am out of ideas and unable to find solution online.

Comment: Can you verify there are no 3rd party programs associated with power/power plans? I've been seeing a lot of laptops with OEM software that will attempt to control this stuff for you.

Answer (score 1):

You can reset your Power Plans to default by doing the following;

1. Open the [command
   prompt](http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/9702-command-prompt-open-windows-8-a.html)
2. Type **powercfg -restoredefaultschemes** then press <kbd>Enter</kbd>
3. Close the command prompt by typing **exit** then pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>

If that doesn't restore them, try running [System File Checker](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wiki/windows_other-system/system-file-check-sfc-scan-and-repair-system-files/bc609315-da1f-4775-812c-695b60477a93) by doing the following;

1. Open an [elevated command
       prompt](http://pcsupport.about.com/od/commandlinereference/f/elevated-command-prompt.htm) as an administrator
2. Type **SFC /SCANNOW** then press <kbd>Enter</kbd>

After the scan completes, reboot and see if the power plans are fixed.